# Generate CSV , EXCEL file dynamique with lightning web component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, csv, datatable, excel

I have a problem with my code , I want to generate a file ( CSV / XLS ) , but with my code I get nothing , I don't now what is the problem .

Some help please .

```
  <a target="_self" class="slds-button"  href={hrefdata}
                    download={fileName}
                      onclick={downloadCSVFile} 
                    style="margin-left: 1%;">
```

==> JS :

```
 downloadCSVFile(event) {
        console.log('teste file');

        var DetailSets = this.DetailSets;
        var data = [];
        var headerArray = [];
        var csvContentArray = [];


        //Fill out the Header of CSV
        //headerArray.push(' ');
        var regExpr = /[&\/\\#°]/g;
        var delivery = Delivery;
        var deliveryCnt = delivery.replace(regExpr, ".");
        headerArray.push(Cnt);
        headerArray.push(date);
        headerArray.push(Amount);
        data.push(headerArray.join("\t")); 

        for (var i = 0; i < DetailSets.length; i++) { 
            var tempArray = []; 
            tempArray.push(DetailSets[i].Vbln__c);
            tempArray.push(DetailSets[i].Eat__c);
            tempArray.push(DetailSets[i].Amt__c);
            //console.log("tempArray.join() : " + tempArray.join("\t")); 
            data.push(tempArray.join("\t")); 
        }

        var dataString = data.join("\n"); 

        var csvContent = dataString;

    
        var Name = this.Name;
        var fileName = "Export " + Name;
       
        fileName = fileName.replace(/ /g, "_");
        fileName += ".xls";
        var uri = 'data:text/xls;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csvContent);

        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
            var blob = new Blob([csvContent], { type: "text/xls;charset=utf-8;" });
            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
        }
        else {
           
            var link = document.createElement("a");

           
            link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
            link.href = uri;

         
            link.style = "visibility:hidden";

            link.click();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you're using tabs instead of commas, so this is a TSV (Tab-Separated Values) file, not a CSV (Comma-Separated Values) file. This may cause problems in Excel and other programs trying to read the file. Second, `Cnt`, `date`, and `Amount` appear to be undefined. Unless you need the performance increase, consider using the more legible Array.prototype.map method. You also have some unused variables in your code. Finally, don't use `text/xls`, as that isn't a valid mime type. Declaring the file as a CSV should open Excel (or whatever spreadsheet app is installed for CSV). Assuming that the variables are declared elsewhere, here's a more legible version of your code:

```
  downloadCSVFile() {
    const csv = [
      { Vlbn__c: Cnt, Eat__c: date, Amt__c: Amount }, // Field Headers
      ...this.DetailSets, // Record Rows
    ]
      .map((row) => [row.Vlbn__c, row.Eat__c, row.Amt__c].join(",")) // convert to CSV record
      .join("\n"); // and join all records together
    var fileName = `Export ${this.Name}.xls`.replace(" ", "_");
    var uri = `data:text/xls;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(csvContent)}`;
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
      // IE 10+
      var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;" });
      navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else {
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
      link.href = uri;
      link.style = "visibility:hidden";
      link.click();
    }
  }
```